# Terraform AWS communicating between ecs_tasks and ecs_services containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, terraform, containers

I have a deployment of three ECS Tasks/Services, basically a web app, nginx proxy and a postgres database all in ECS Fargate containers. I have tried pursuing several different ways to get the app server to communicate to the database container to no avail.

Currently I have a private bridge network defined in the container definition for the Postgres database, however I am not sure if it works because the services are FARGATE launch types (which only run with awsvpc network_mode.

```
resource "docker_network" "private_bridge_network" {
  name     = "app_network_internal"
  driver   = "bridge"
  internal = true
}
```

```
"networks_advanced": [
            {
                "name": "${docker_network.private_bridge_network.name}",
                "aliases": [
                    "${var.postgres_network_alias}"
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I have also considered defining all tasks in one ecs task definition but I think that is further from the end goal here.

If anybody has any experience communicating between containers deployed with Terraform into AWS any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's been a while since I deployed to ECS, but how have you set up the Security Groups of your ECS Services? Are they blocking connectivity between the services? Other than that, have you looked through [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-connecting-services.html)?

Comment: Are the containers running in the same ECS task/service, or different ECS tasks/services?  Also, running Postgres on ECS Fargate is an **extremely bad idea**. You have to setup all the Postgres clustering features yourself, you have to manage writer instance failover yourself, you have to manage automated backups yourself, and you have to use EFS volumes for your persistent file storage which is going to be *slow*! You are basically re-inventing AWS RDS Postgres (or AWS Aurora Postgres) but your version is going to be worse in every way because of the limitations of Fargate.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried pursuing several different ways to get the app server to communicate to the database container to no avail.

If your containers are parts of the same task, they share the network stack and [can communicate through localhost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-networking.html).

If they're not, the AWS-native way of dealing with it is putting these tasks on a EC2 Cluster and Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer in front of them. So that would be something like this:

1. Define a cluster with PostgreSQL tasks.
2. Define an internal NLB targeting the database cluster.
3. Define a cluster with web-app tasks, passing the DNS name or the database NLB as an environment variable.
4. Define an externally accessible ALB targeting the web-app cluster.

If looks like the Nginx proxy is playing the role of application balancers in your setup. The problem with it is that there is no straightforward way to retrieve IPs of Fargate tasks in terraform. Even if it were, the cluster can restart the tasks, giving them new IPs, so you would have to comminucate this fact to Nginx. Native AWS load balancers take care of that for you.

Note that all above answers the question as asked, about networking aspects of connecting containers. As Mark B. mentions in the comments, Fargate does not have permanent storage, and NLB will only work if the cluster is either single-task or only comprises read-only replicas (with the master elsewhere). Fargate tasks are more suited for batch-type jobs that have defined input and output, not for running services on them.

Comment: An NLB in front of a PostgreSQL cluster isn't really going to work, because all writes have to go to one instance in the Postgres cluster, and the NLB is just going to send traffic to random instances.